# How to convert a JdbcTemplate to Flux in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflux, reactive

I have an existing service that returns a `List<Item>`. The items are created by multiple subsequent database calls, parsings and aggregations (much more complex than in this example).

How can I convert the following example to `Flux`, so that my results are streamed, instead of having to aggregate all items before in memory?

```
@RestController
public class BookingInfoServlet {
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbc;

    @GetMapping(value = "/export", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<Item> export(String productType) {
        List<Item> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < jdbc.count(); i++) {
            List<String> refIds = jdbc.queryForList("SELECT ref_id FROM products where type = ? LIMIT 1000 OFFSET = ?", String.class, productType, i);
            for (String id : refIds) {
                Map map = jdbc.queryForMap("SELECT <anything> ... where some_id = ?, id);
                Item item = new Item();
                item.setName(map.get("name"));
                item.setCode(map.getCode("code"));
                item.set...
                list.add(item);
            }

            //TODO how to convert to Flux here and already send the chunks back into the stream?
        }

        return list; //TODO how to convert to Flux?
    }
}
```

First problem: here I'm first fetching all results from the first query into memory, then iterating and forming all my `Item`s in memory, then returning the whole list.

Therefore I'm trying to return `Flux<Item>`. BUT: how can I now acutally return the fluxes when using `JdbcTemplate`?

As there is no async `mysql` java driver, I probably have to paginate the database lookup in chunks like 1000, then prepare 1000 items and already stream them back to the client. Then fetch the next 1000 items. But how can I get them directly into the stream?

Comment: I thought I did that. My question is: how can I send back my prepared chunk list of items into a `Flux<Item>` stream, so that the client always receives the responses in chunks. It does not necessarly have to be 1000 chunks, it could as well be one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  public Flux<Item> export(String productType) {
    int pageSize = 1000;
    int count = jdbc.count();
    return Flux.range(0, count / pageSize) //page numbers
        .flatMapIterable(pageNumber ->
            jdbc.queryForList("SELECT ref_id FROM products where type = ? LIMIT ? OFFSET = ?",
                String.class,
                productType,
                pageSize,
                pageNumber * pageSize))
        .map(id -> {
          Map map = jdbc.queryForMap("SELECT <anything> ... where some_id = ?", id);
          Item item = new Item();
          //
          //
          return item;
        });
  }
```